# Issue facing with JQuery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a function once both the animation within a function is executed. Hence i chose jquery promise. But the .done function is getting triggered as soon as the first animation for '.block1' is done, it is not waiting for the animation with '.block2'.

HTML:

```
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
doAnimation().done(function () {
    alert('promise');
});
});

function doAnimation() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $('.block1').animate({
        'marginLeft': '200px', 'width': '400px'
    }, 2000, function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    $('.block2').animate({
        'marginLeft': '0px', 'height': '400px'
    }, 4500, function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

CSS:

```
.block1,.block2
    {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:orange;
        border:1px solid #ccc;    
    }
```

Comment: I think its working check https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/to6df3h5/ ..done() execute after complete execution of animation

Comment: you want alert message after  the second div animation finished ?

Answer (score 4):

A Promise is resolved as soon as `resolve` is called on it once, if you want to wait for two events, you need to create two promises and wait for both of them, for example:

```
function doAnimation() {
    var deferred1 = $.Deferred();
    var deferred2 = $.Deferred();
    $('.block1').animate({
        'marginLeft': '200px', 'width': '400px'
    }, 2000, function () {
        deferred1.resolve();
    });

    $('.block2').animate({
        'marginLeft': '0px', 'height': '400px'
    }, 4500, function () {
        deferred2.resolve();
    });

    return $.when(deferred1, deferred2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit and now it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/bys2gbt1/

What was happening was that you only used 1 promise for both animations. The promise was resolved when the fastest animation was done (and so done was being called before the second animation finished).

You just need to use another promise for the second animation and way for them both. Here's what's different:

```
var deferred1 = $.Deferred(),
    deferred2 = $.Deferred();
$('.block1').animate({
    'marginLeft': '200px', 'width': '400px'
}, 2000, function () {
    deferred1.resolve();
});

$('.block2').animate({
    'marginLeft': '0px', 'height': '400px'
}, 4500, function () {
    deferred2.resolve();
});

return deferred1.promise()
    .then(function () { 
        return deferred2.promise();
    });
```

The only major difference is that I am waiting for both promises.

LE: As Thayne has done, you could also use

```
$.when(deferred1, deferred2);
```